# Passing JSON data with details of an item from URL that uses an ID using PHP, Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I have to get JSON data with details of an item from URL that uses dynamic ID e.g `https://www.example.com/api/prDetails?prId=4100275`

I managed to make a loop to list all products in `products.php` page and assigned each its id as e.g `data-id=4100275`.

```html
<a data-id="4100275">Coffee Beans</div>
<a data-id="6530113">Bananas</div>

<!--Display Product Details inside the div below-->
<div id="prDetails"></div>
```

So I want to click on a product item and display its details in a `<div id="prDetails"></div>` on the same page without refreshing or getting out of the `products.php` page.

**EDIT MAJOR ISSUE**

How to pass the `data-id=".$id."` and use it in test.php.

```html
<script> 
   $(document).ready(function() {
    
      $("div.item-link a").on("click", function(e) {
    
         e.preventDefault();
    
         $.ajax({
    
            type: 'POST', // IF you want to pass the id in the query stringthe id in the query string
            url: "test.php?prId=" + e.currentTarget.dataset.id, 
    
            success: function(data) {
               $("#prDetails").html(data);
            }
        });
    
     });
  });
</script>
```

Then on `test.php` use `<?php echo $_GET['prId']; ?>` to get the id that was passed.

Thank you

Comment: Perfect you know what you need ([`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) + [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch)), what you have tried?

Comment: @simone-rossaini Tried getting an idea [from ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54844678/get-data-id-from-url-using-javascript-ajax) but still could not find a work around.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Why is this question tagged with PHP, JSON, and AJAX, but does not contain a single line of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@DanielOmara the example you are looking is a good starting point.

I suggest you to assign the same class to all  tags that contain *data-id* or better to assign a class to their conatainer, like so:

```html
<div class="item-link">
    <a data-id="4100275">Coffee Beans</a>
    <a data-id="6530113">Bananas</a>
</div>
```

then you can use a selector to add an event listener to the  tags:

```javascript
$(document).ready(function() {

   $("div.item-link a").on("click", function(e) {

       e.preventDefault();

       $.ajax({

          type: 'POST',
          url: "test.php?prId=" + e.currentTarget.dataset.id, 

          success: function(data) {
             $("#prDetails").html(data);
          }
       });

     });
});
```

Now in your *test.php* you can read the $_GET['prId'], get the details related to this *id* and echo the data you want to display in the *prDetails*

Comment: Tried to console log the data and got an error  `from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` so did some edit on original post with some modifications on your code.

Comment: @DanielOmara that's ok, I have used your example code for my answer, if you have changed something, it's a good idea to adapt my answer to the changes

Comment: @DanielOmara I've added a parameter name to the query string, I think it's better so.
In this way you can read the $_GET['prId'] parameter in *test.php* (I've used the previous parameter name)